# Switching branches in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfvc

I'm used to working with VS+Git.
With the GIT plugin, given a project, you can seamlessly change between branches of your code just by clicking the bottom-right dropdown and voila!
I'm looking for a similar way to do this with TFS! I don't mind re-downloading everything, I just want to know a fast way to change between branches. I find it hard to believe that I really have to close the solution and open another every time?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you mean with TFVC, as Git repo's hosted in TFS will give you teh same fast branch switching.

The fast branch switching is one of the key concepts in Git, unfortunately, it's not one of the key concepts of TFVC and there is no easy fast branch switching when using TFVC.

Comment: in my "recent items" folder i'll have my project name repeat all over the place?!? =(

Comment: Yups. Each branch you've opened... Visual Studio doesn't do anything with the branch information in any respect except to populate the branch/merge windows.